# DIfference between "in" and "inside"

Tags: prepositions

> Galactic Republic will deliver large payloads to orbit **inside a composite fairing**, but the rocket can also carry the manned spacecraft.

Does **inside a composite fairing** function as an attributive or adverbial phrase?

Can I use **in a composite fairing** instead?

Comment: As an American citizen, I am bound by export control regulations that prevent me from discussing many details of satellite technology with people who are not American citizens.  This particular regulation was put in as a reaction to Americans asking the Chinese why their rockets' fairings repeatedly failed.  So while I would be happy to address this grammatical issue in a completely different context, neither I nor many other stack exchange contributors can legally answer this question.

Comment: I think you are stretching the point here. It's a grammatical issue, not a technological issue. I don't care about the rocket technology. And I'm not even trying to tempt you to do it.

Comment: @Jasper That's patently ridiculous and a completely wrong assessment. Even if what you said somehow applied to everyone who used this site (which it doesn't; there's lots of non-American users, plus your legal analysis is highly suspect) and you were correct (which you aren't; NASA and SpaceX both publish all sorts of details well beyond the definition of "fairing" as it relates to rocketry), this question is about *grammar*, not rocket science. Whether this is *an attributive or adverbial phrase* has nothing to do with anything other than grammar. There is zero reason to close this question.

Comment: According to http://www.pmddtc.state.gov/ECR/index.html, the U.S. government is currently revising the Export Control Regulations.
The rules still remain a thorny mess, and many of the proposed changes have not gone into effect yet.
In particular, http://www.pmddtc.state.gov/FR/2014/79FR27180.pdf says that the strict rules of USML Category XV paragraph (f) still cover the original scenario about fairing failures.

Comment: @Jasper Whatever, just don't vote against it. I don't expect a US citizen to answer my question. A UK citizen would be enough, so it's fricking ridiculous to vote against it. If you really want to help, just walk away.

Comment: Um, no.  This is the exact same problem.  Please change the example so that it does not involve aerospace.  And considering that your employer sells Long March launch services to American companies, I would hope that your company would discourage you from putting potential customers and former customers in fraught legal situations.

Comment: I'd like to suggest an alternative example sentence, "This time James Bond will carry his high tech gun inside his suitcase."

Comment: @Jasper I never knew a regulation can prevent someone to opine whether the phrase is 'attributive' or 'adverbial' :P

Comment: @EsotericScreenName agreed. The beauty of the site is it precisely talks about the language and nothing else. Overly reading between the lines makes no sense.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you, but you might want to consult a lawyer. @Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Inside a composite fairing* is an adverbial phrase here. It specifies the manner in which the *payloads* will be *delivered*. If you replaced *composite fairing* with *rocket*, the grammar would be the same (though not the semantics, obviously), but hopefully the simplified example makes it easier to understand.

A *fairing* is a piece of a rocket designed to shield cargo from the atmosphere during launch. Here's a brief synopsis from [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_fairing):

> A payload fairing is a nose cone used to protect a spacecraft (launch vehicle payload) against the impact of dynamic pressure and aerodynamic heating during launch through an atmosphere.

*[Composite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/composite)* is an adjective modifying *fairing*, and it means that it's constructed from multiple materials.

The entire phrase refines the meaning of the verb *deliver* by telling us the precise manner of action. [Damkerng T. offers this example sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32144/difference-between-in-and-inside#comment60428_32144) with parallel grammar:

> This time James Bond will carry his high tech gun inside his suitcase.

Here, *inside his suitcase* serves the same grammatical function as *inside a composite fairing*; it tells us how *James bond will carry his high tech gun*.

> Can I use **in a composite fairing instead**?

Yes, you can replace *inside* with *in* and the meaning will still be essentially the same. *Inside* is the better choice, though, because it's more specific than *in*, and in this case, the payload is literally enclosed within the fairing. *In* doesn't entail enclosure but *inside* does. Take a look at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/23281/6407) for more on the nuanced differences between these two prepositions.